# namespaces in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, namespaces, coffeescript

I'd like to use namespaces as one would in javascript by using the keyword "with", but CoffeeScript reports this as a reserved keyword and refuses to compile is there any way I could use namespaces in cs?

In particular, I want to include a CoffeeScript file dynamically (trusted source), like loading models for a database schema, but I want the included script to have access to a local namespace.

---

**Edit:**

Here's what I want to do. I am setting up a web framework that maps the directory tree to an application based on express and mongoose. For example, there's a sub-directory 'models' that contains a file 'user.coffee' with code like this inside:

```
name:
    type: String
    unique: on
profiles: [ Profile ]
```

Whereby `Profile` is a class that sits in a local object named `model`. When the user model is being loaded, I wanted it to access the model classes that sit in my local model store.

My work-around for now was to write `model.Profile` into the file 'user.coffee'. Hope it is clear what I mean.

---

**2nd Edit**

Here's how I did it without using `with`:

user.coffee

```
name:
    type: String
    unique: on
profiles: [ @profile ]
```

profile.coffee

```
content: String
```

And here's how it's dynamically loaded:

```
for fm in fs.readdirSync "#{base}/models"
    m = path.basename fm, '.coffee'
    schema[m] = (()->
        new Schema coffee.eval (
            fs.readFileSync "#{base}/models/#{fm}", 'utf8'
        ), bare: on
    ).call model
    mongoose.model m, schema[m]
    model[m] = mongoose.model m
```

Seems an okay solution to me.

Comment: I'm afraid your edit hasn't made your intentions much clearer.  Could you add representative code for `model.Profile` and how you would like to use it?

Comment: Stick an `@` in front of `Profile` when defining it: `class @Profile`. Since `this` is `global`, that'll make it a global named `Profile`. No changes needed to `user.coffee` (though you could write `@Profile` to make it clearer that you're referencing a global).

Comment: Profile is a mongoose Schema, and it is defined dynamically the same way User is: via a CoffeeScript file. profile.coffee in this case. See https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose and http://mongoosejs.com/ - so I cannot define it globally. Despite that, I wanted to avoid global definitions. However, I'll give the @ a try - it's a synonym for `this` in CoffeeScript, right?

Comment: Well, if `@` compiles to `this`, I couldn't use it in other functions, like callbacks, since it would refer to that function...

Comment: By the way, I now consider using `coffee.eval` not such a good idea. Instead, one could just use `require` that will resolve coffe-script files as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Coco fork of CoffeeScript supports a `with` syntax; see https://github.com/satyr/coco/wiki/additions. However, that syntax simply sets the value of `this` to the target object in a block, rather than compiling to the problematic and deprecated `with` keyword.

Let's say that you wanted to emulate Coco's `with` syntax in CoffeeScript. You'd do something like this:

```
withObj = (obj, func) -> func.call obj
```

Then you could write

```
withObj = (obj, func) -> func.call obj
withObj annoyingly.lengthy.obj.reference, ->
  @foo = 'bar'
  @bar = 'baz'
```

Of course, in such simple cases, it's better to use a utility function like jQuery or Underscore's `extend`:

```
_.extend annoyingly.lengthy.obj.reference, foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz'
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I used the call method. Forgot about it.

Answer (score 6):

Having someone else's opinion forced on you? It's Hack Time™!

```
o =
  a: 1
  b: 2
  c: 3

`with(o) {//`
  alert a
`}`
```

"Compiles" to:

```
var o;
o = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
with(o) {//;
alert(a);
};
```

It's a pity that this is another area where Doug Crockford's opinion is taken as gospel. [`with` Statement Considered Harmful](http://with%20Statement%20Considered%20Harmful) rejects it on the basis of ambiguity of property writes, but ignores its usefulness when used with a *read-only* context object, such as a context object which defines a DSL-like API.

Comment: Regardless, it's a syntax error in both CS and ES5 strict mode and should thus be avoided by responsible engineers.

Comment: It's not just Crockford, though. As lawnsea points out, `with` is deprecated and disallowed in ES5 strict mode. (That alone is enough reason for CoffeeScript not to compile to it.) It also has a dramatic performance impact in most JS environments (try [this benchmark](http://jsbin.com/imidu/edit), for instance).

Comment: ES5 strict mode is [*opt-in*](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/), so `with` won't be going anywhere for those who find it useful in specific scenarios in which it's genuinely useful.

Comment: This answer is **wrong**. If you arrived here from google *DO NOT DO THIS*. What happens if coffee decides to include `"use strict";` in the compiled JS at a later date? Don't inline JS into CoffeeScript unless you have no other option. In this case, destructuring assignment or Trevor's answer will work just fine.

Comment: Just tried it and it works fine. Thanks! However, if there was a solution to do it without `with` I'd prefer that one...

Comment: @insin: In the end I sticked with the hint from Trevor. Anyway +1 for you on the nice post :-)

Comment: I wouldn't say that this answer is "wrong"; it's not the approach I'd recommend, but it's a clever hack. CoffeeScript is unlikely to add its own "use strict" declaration any time soon; see [issue 845](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/845).

Comment: @lawnsea It's the correct answer to "How do I use `with` with CoffeeScript" ;-) Whether you use `with` at all is for you to answer based on your own opinion and need.

Comment: That's a pretty nifty hack! Only that deserves a plus. I guess people downvoting that were just jealous they didn't have imagination as sharp.

Comment: @lawnsea Good point.  Actually, as I see now, Coffee-Script already does include "use strict;" into all compiled JavaScript files.

Answer (score 3):

No.  However, you can use [destructuring assignment](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#destructuring) to achieve a similar effect.

```
{foo, bar, baz} = require 'toocoollib'
foo 'whoa!'
```

You should also be aware that the `with` keyword is deprecated and is a [syntax error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode#Simplifying_variable_uses) in ES5 strict mode. The consensus among mainstream JS hackers is that `with` is a bad idea.

If you posted an example of what you would like to do, I could give a more specific answer.

Comment: By the way, I am using node, which doesn't seem to complain about `with` until now. I have specified the example and hope it is somehow clear what I want to achieve :-)

Comment: The destructuring assignment doesn't work for me, because I don't know the names in advance. But I have found another possibility using an anonymous function and the call method on it, passing the unknown object I want to defer.

Answer (score 2):

Just found that on the CoffeeScript FAQ page about "Variable Importing":

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/FAQ

It seems, that the use of this technique is discouraged in CoffeeScript and not supported.